# How to return part of the page based on url parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

Lets say I have an HTML page like this:

```
<body>
..
   <div id="importantStuff">
      <p>Important content</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

From time to time, a (c#) server needs to grab the contents of `<div id="importantStuff">` and process it.

So I thought one way to do so is to add a parameter to the url that the server uses to invoke the page (like `&giveMeImportantStuff=true`) and then I write a JavaScript/jQ function to return the important stuff.

(One reason that I want to use JS/jQ is that I already have to do some processing on the page elements, when that parameter is true.)

**So, basically my question is how to return parts of the page based on the url parameters.**

---

Edit 1 (60 min after posting):

I achieved what I want by using:

```
var stuff = $("#importantStuff").html();
$('body').html(stuff);
```

But, isn't there a nicer way?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I believe this sort of question has been answered multiple times too so maybe a little research would help you find the answers you're looking for?

Comment: I have searched many questions on SO, but most of the results are populating fields based on the parameters, not grabbing a part of the page and returning that!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to read query string parameters, check the value of the parameter, and read the content of the div element:

```
const params = window.location.search
.substr(1)
.split('&')
.reduce((obj, x, i, arr) => {
    var [key, value] = x.split('=')
    obj[key] = value
    return obj
}, {})

if (params.giveMeImportantStuff === 'true') {
 const content = document.querySelector('#importantStuff').innerHTML

 // do something with content
}
```

Comment: Im already populating stuff and manipulating some thing like contents based on , so you mean when I am done, use `document.contents = contents`